# How to convert between MIME-Types for blob/buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, wav

**The Problem:**

I record Audio from within the Browser which gives me a BLOB when the recording is done:

```
let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/webm;codecs=opus' });
```

Changing the mime-type here won't help since the chunks already come with their MIME-Type which is `audio/webm;codecs=opus` for almost all browsers. So can not do anything here.

Sending this Blob via XHR to an node.js server will result in recieving a buffer from that blob:

Client:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/audio', true);
xhr.send(blob);
```

Server:

```
app.post('/audio' , (req, res) =>{
    req.on('readable',()=>{
        let buffer = req.read();
        // sending this buffer to the external API results in error 
        // since it expects the mime-type audio/wav 
    });

    res.send({msg: 'success'}); 
});
```

Most solutions out there require you to write the file to your disk and convert that ( [ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg)).
Others use Browser-features which are experimental or not compatible with older browsers...
I also tried using the [wavfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavefile) npm package, but that creates a corrupted file if i try writing it with the UInt8Array from that webm-formatted buffer (playable file but it only contains noise and is much shorter than the actual recording should be)

There must be a **simple solution** to convert the binary data server side, right? Best I could wish for would be a function `convertWebmBufferToWavBuffer`.

Comment: Have you seen this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/audiobuffer-to-wav ?

Comment: @Trobol I tried using it together with the [audio-buffer-from](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-buffer-from) package to convert the buffer to audioBuffer and then convert the audioBuffer to a wav formatted buffer ([audiobuffer-to-wav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audiobuffer-to-wav)). If write that to a new File with `fs.writeFileSync` the file only contains some noise similar to the problem described with the wavfile package.

Comment: Are you sure that the audio is recording correctly? Have you tried playing it without the wav conversion?

Comment: yes inside the browser it plays correct when integrated into the audio html tag... I keep digging for that solution...sounds like that must be possible somehow and sounds like the best solution